# Formatting strings based on other variables

Tags: c++

Working on an assignment for class that asks us for inputs such that we create a "corral" based on numbers from input. I'm having just an infuriatingly hard time trying to get the spacing right based on another variable. The corral should look something like:

```
|==|==|==|
:        :
-        -
:        :
|==|==|==|
```

My issue being the empty space in the center (which should be based on the length of the top/bottom). Setw() works to some degree, but again, just an infuriating time. Here's the rest of what I have so far:`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

main () {

    int theloop,nsfp,ewfp,count,nsfp2,ewfp2,nsfpw,count2;
    char choice;
    theloop = 0;

    while (theloop < 1) {

        do { 
            cout << "How many North/South Fence posts? ";
            cin >> nsfp;
            if (nsfp < 2)
            cout << "Value must be at least 2, please try again\n";
            else if (nsfp > 10)
                nsfp = 10;
        } while (nsfp < 2);

        do { 
            cout << "How many East/West Fence posts? ";
            cin >> ewfp;
            if (ewfp < 2)
                cout << "Value must be at least 2, please try again\n";
            else if (ewfp > 10)
                nsfp = 10;
        } while (ewfp < 2);

        for (count = 1; count <= nsfp; count++) {
            cout << "|";
            nsfp2 = nsfp - 1;
            for (count = 1; count <= nsfp2; count++) {
                cout << "==|";
                nsfpw = count;
            }
        }

        for (count = 1; count < ewfp; count++) {
            cout << "\n:" << " " << ":" << endl;
            ewfp2 = ewfp;
            for (count = 1; count < ewfp2; count++){
                cout << "-" << setw(nsfpw) << "-" << "\n:" << ":" << endl;
            }   
        }

        cout << "\n" << nsfp << endl;
        cout << ewfp;
        theloop = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to create a spacing variable that in your example contains 8 spaces. That way you can just write it out between lines. If you are unsure how to know that it is 8, try out manually drawing some corrals, counting and doing the math to figure out the relationships. Note due to this being homework I am glossing over your other problems and focusing on the one you asked.

Comment: Tip.  If you need a "block of spaces" you can always use `std::string` like `std::string space_block(number_of_spaces, ' ');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is this. The number of spaces comes out to be

> 3 * nsfp - 4;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

main () {

    int theloop,nsfp,ewfp,count,nsfp2,ewfp2,nsfpw,count2;
    char choice;
    theloop = 0;

    while (theloop < 1) {

    do { 
    cout << "How many North/South Fence posts? ";
    cin >> nsfp;
    if (nsfp < 2)
        cout << "Value must be at least 2, please try again\n";
    else if (nsfp > 10)
        nsfp = 10;
    } while (nsfp < 2);

    do { 
    cout << "How many East/West Fence posts? ";
    cin >> ewfp;
    if (ewfp < 2)
        cout << "Value must be at least 2, please try again\n";
    else if (ewfp > 10)
        nsfp = 10;
    } while (ewfp < 2);

    for (count = 1; count <= nsfp; count++) {
        cout << "|";
        nsfp2 = nsfp - 1;
        for (count = 1; count <= nsfp2; count++) {
            cout << "==|";
            nsfpw = count;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    int spaces = 3 * nsfp - 4;
    for (count = 1; count < ewfp; count++) {
        cout << ":";
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << ":\n-";
        ewfp2 = ewfp;
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++){
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "-\n";   
    }
    for (count = 1; count <= nsfp; count++) {
        cout << "|";
        nsfp2 = nsfp - 1;
        for (count = 1; count <= nsfp2; count++) {
            cout << "==|";
            nsfpw = count;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n" << nsfp << endl;
    cout << ewfp;
    theloop = 1;
    }
}
```

A cleaner way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

main () {

    int theloop,nsfp,ewfp,count,nsfp2,ewfp2,nsfpw,count2;
    char choice;
    theloop = 0;

    while (theloop < 1) {

    do { 
    cout << "How many North/South Fence posts? ";
    cin >> nsfp;
    if (nsfp < 2)
        cout << "Value must be at least 2, please try again\n";
    else if (nsfp > 10)
        nsfp = 10;
    } while (nsfp < 2);

    do { 
    cout << "How many East/West Fence posts? ";
    cin >> ewfp;
    if (ewfp < 2)
        cout << "Value must be at least 2, please try again\n";
    else if (ewfp > 10)
        nsfp = 10;
    } while (ewfp < 2);

    for (count = 1; count <= nsfp; count++) {
        cout << "|";
        nsfp2 = nsfp - 1;
        for (count = 1; count <= nsfp2; count++) {
            cout << "==|";
            nsfpw = count;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    string spaces(3 * nsfp - 4, ' ');
    for (count = 1; count < ewfp; count++) {
        cout << ":" << spaces << ":\n";
        cout << "-" << spaces << "-\n";
    }
    for (count = 1; count <= nsfp; count++) {
        cout << "|";
        nsfp2 = nsfp - 1;
        for (count = 1; count <= nsfp2; count++) {
            cout << "==|";
            nsfpw = count;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n" << nsfp << endl;
    cout << ewfp;
    theloop = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This comes very close to doing someone's homework for them!

Comment: I'd like to ask how you came about that answer for the spacing. It is indeed correct, I'm just confused as to how you got there

Comment: @ChrisU Just count the number of spaces. 3 spaces per fence except for the last one. 1 space for the last fence less 2 spaces for the characters per line. so 3 * (n-1) + 1 -2 = 3 *n - 4

Comment: @user3286661 Oy, I see it now, thank you! I should really have more sleep before I attempt these things, lol.